How to dynamic serve gradio content in FastAPI on runtime?
I have a business request. I now have N gradio apps, the number increases and decreases dynamically, and the content will also changes.
So I want to look up the gradio app by id in a routing interface, and at runtime return the gradio app's HTML content as a response from the server.
The pseudo-code is as follows:
@app.get("/gradio_response/{gradio_app_id}") 
def render_gradio_app(gradio_app_id: int): 
    # read gradio block from src file.
    gradio_blocks = foundGradioAppById(gradio_app_id)
    return renderHTMLContent(gradio_blocks)

The foundGradioAppById function I had implement,but How can I implement renderHTMLContent?
# this code can't meet the request, because blocksApp File will be CRUD on runtime.
app = gr.mount_gradio_app(app, blocks, '/some_path')

Any ideas are welcome,Thank you very much!

This and this might prove helpful.

You can't render HTML from fastapi more than once in a HTTP connection session, as it's limited by a HTTP protocol, but you can return JS code that will dynamically update contents of a page on your web browser.
Looks like you need a fastapi.WebSocket or socketio app (you can mount it into a FastAPI app) or just polling on frontend side. There are examples of JS code for frontend in a docs. Frontend connects to backend and gathers information in runtime (as you set up on backend). Also you can use fastapi.StreamingResponse as a one-way connection channel, but you also need to return JS code that will read blocks of HTTP page body as stream.
